# Django CSRF and Sessions

Tags: django, session, cookies, csrf

I'm a little fuzzy on the specifics of Django's CSRF protection. While it is easy enough to implement, I was under the impression that the CSRF token should be session-independent. So when a user logs out, and someone else logs in (perhaps on the same machine), the CSRF token would change.

However, I have noticed through Chrome developer tools that the CSRF token in the cookie is valid for an entire year, and does not change (unless you delete it, of course, in which case it is regenerated). This means that the cookie's CSRF token persists through different user sessions.

Is there a vulnerability here? Have I implemented something incorrectly? Or is this intended and I am just missing how the protection works?

Comment: I'm reading now that Django's CSRF protection relies on the "Double Submit Cookie" principal to repel these attacks, but further clarification would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is no issue. Django handles it all very well - it was the beta version which did not work / had this feature disabled. The token persisted through user sessions, but this was just due to having a beta version running the project. With a release version, all is well and protected.